# RNDC Sync Failed - could not set file modification time of /etc/bind/slave

Tags: sync, bind

1. I have setup transfer to IPs & master/slave directories/files
2. Added /etc/bind/rndc.key file with the same pass-phrase on both master/slave
3. Permission items inside /etc/bind/slave are -rw-r--r-- 
   (Also tried -rw-rw-rw without any success)
4. Edited /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named

Added

/etc/bind/slave/** rw,

/etc/bind/master/** rw,

/etc/bind/ rw,

I then do sudo /etc/init.d/aparmor restart & then run rndc reload test.com (Zone name)

I wait like 5-10 minutes and go to "vi /var/log/syslog" & it compares the serial number between the Master & Slave but then I get these issues:-

ns named [939]: zone test.com/IN: refresh: could not set file modification time of '/etc/bind/slave/test.com': permission denied

+

ns named [939] dumping master file: /etc/bind/slave/tmp-FEhwr4afaX: open: permission denied

Using Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS.

Hopefully someone can help me get this RNDC (Sync) occurring as I am out of ideas at the moment.

(Tried modifying folder/file permissions & edited apparmor without any luck)

Also since I migrated from a Openbsd bind9 to Ubuntu bind9 my files structure is a slightly different as I only have a single named configuration file

eg.
master

slave

standard

named.conf

bind.keys

rndc.key

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue myself.

1. Create a folder called slaves under /etc/bind/
2. Go into named.conf & replace /etc/bind/slave with /etc/bind/slaves & let it propergate.

You don't need any of the zone files as it will grab them from the Primary name server.

1. RNDC reload zonename (Speeds it up for that single domain)

I think because I copied the slave folder from another system the permissions were root:bind & the new folder that was created was bind:bind which is why it works.

But it's odd I did change the permissions on the folder/files to bind:bind but the main thing is its working now.

Hopefully this helps others who are migrating form an OpenBSD Name Server etc

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer did not fix the exact same issue for me, here is what I had to do (which I searched online without success and tried to fix this for 2 hours)

I had to simply modify one line in `/etc/default/bind`

From:

```
# run resolvconf?
RESOLVCONF=no
```

To:

```
# run resolvconf?
RESOLVCONF=yes
```

Comment: That is certainly not the solution to the stated problem.

Comment: Had the exact same issue, tried everything I got from google, this worked.